# Positioning a Div on Canvas Image with Same Cordinates of SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, canvas

I Have a usecase where I have a div which is draggable across a SVG Element. Its a Sticky Note which is placed near to individual Elements in SVG, I then Take a SnapShot of it Using `canvas.drawImage()` .

The Problem is Its positioning is not proper As I start to drag it from left to right, Its distance from the Element in SVG starts Changing.
I am attaching couple of Screenshot to clarify the situation

Element Positioned on SVG: [image1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt7BJ.png)

Element Appearing on Canvas after Draw: [image1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsO4J.png)

2nd Element Position on SVG [image2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq1dI.png)

2nd Element Appearing on Canvas after Draw:
 [image2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKyKY.png)

As you can see in image 1.1 and 2.1 I have position the element on two different bars but they are on exactly same cordinates wrt bar.

But in Images 1.2 and 2.2 both the elemnts should have been on the same position wrt the bar but both are different. As I am going towards right the red Box is drifting towards left.
I want both the boxes to be in same position relative to the boxses.

Here is the Code I used to get the pixel co-ordinates from the entire svg

```js
var pt = $("#bar-chart-modal").find(".si-dataviz-bar")[0].createSVGPoint();  // Created once for document
              pt.x = e.clientX;
              pt.y = e.clientY;
              // The cursor point, translated into svg coordinates
              var cursorpt = pt.matrixTransform($("#bar-chart-modal").find(".si-dataviz-bar")[0].getScreenCTM().inverse());
              console.log("(" + cursorpt.x + ", " + cursorpt.y + ")");
```

This code runs whenever I drag the Element around which gives me X and Y. Then I use these cordinates in drawImage() like this

```js
 ctx.drawImage(footerImg, self.pagex, self.pagey);
```

Note: As I am not able to append the Div element to SVG it is appended to the parent div of SCG which has the same width and height as the SVG
Can anyone please help and tell me where I am going wrong

Thanks

Comment: Its much better to represent a mini working example that domstrate the error

Comment: Its kind of a project so half of the things are coming from one component and other from another compoenents, The D3 Library for the chart is elsewhere, so thats why I havent posted the demo, I apologise for that, But I am willing to provide specific piece of info you require.

Comment: I dont know what kind of code you have so i cant be specific about what is required. You need to understand that these kinds of problems need the whole code. so we could look at the big picture. Well maby someone could figure it out as for me i would need the whole code to see and at best a mini demo.

Comment: An issue you may have: when you click the div for dragging there must be a distance between the point where you click and the left upper corner of the div. Every time you click this distance is different.

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here.  You will likely need to provide some sort of [mcve] to get a good answer.  But it looks like you are positioning the image at the coordinates of your mouse.  Instead I would have expected you would be using the coordinates the top left of your div.